# How to make exponential function "more convex" while keeping desired intercepts unchanged?

Tags: probability, exponential-function

### Background

Hey everyone, it's been a few years since college math, and I'm a bit out of practice. I'm currently working on using the exponential function to model the probability of an event happening. Right now, I've set N to 50, which means that when X hits 50, the probability of the event happening is 100%.

**The function I am using right now is this:**

$$
f(x)=e^{\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{50}x}-1
$$

**The graph of the function looks like this:**

[image]

### Question

The issue is that it is not "convex" enough for my taste. I'd like the probabilities for the earlier inputs (X=0, 1, 2, 3, ...) to be lower, while "backloading" the end – increasing the probabilities for the later inputs (X=..., 47, 48, 49, 50). Nevertheless, I'd like to maintain the same intercepts at (0, 0) and (N, 1). Could someone help me out?

Comment: You could take your current function and raise it to the power $\alpha$, i.e. use $f(x) = \left(2^{x/N}-1\right)^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha \ge 1$ is a parameter you choose to get your desired convexity (higher values of $\alpha$ will make it 'more convex'). Here is a link to a graph of the function where you can drag the slider for $\alpha$ to see the effect of varying it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lduup7gs8x.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Oh, this is actually perfect! Thank you so much! I've been experimenting with various constants for nearly an hour now without success.

Comment: Welcome! $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Also just realized my entire equation simplifies to $2^x$, lol 